# Interactive Report - Sort and filter formated column

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have a simple view which holds a duration in seconds as a number and a formated string as the other column

The numbers can be negative and are "formated" like this:

`-60` is `-00h 01m 00s`

`60` is `+00h 01m 00s`

and so on....

To sort my data, I formated my number column in the interactive report with the text(static ID) from the string column.

So far so good. ( I can now sort by this number/column type )

However I can't make it to work to set the filter as a string and then use the return value from the LOV to set the filter...

Any idea on how to accomplish this?

I need everything numbered on the backend of the column for sorting/filtering and the actual string on the front for the column as display and filtering.

Thank you for your help in advance.

I am using APEX 18.2

Example:

Table "Test" is given with 2 columns:

Duration_Number(Number) & Duration_String (varchar)

In this table are e.g. 3 entries like these:

- 120, '+0h 02m 00s'
- -60, '-0h 01m 00s'
- 60,  '+0h 01m 00s'

The interactive report should only display the string, yet should be able to sort by the corresponding number!

In order to sort this column you may format the DURATION_NUMBER column with the #DURATION_STRING# ID (under Column Formatting => HTML Expression)
This way you can now sort it correctly.

However the filter (dropdown list), still shows the distinct DURATION_NUMBER list.

So I created a LoV with the DURATION_STRING as Display Value and the DURATION_NUMBER as the Return Value. 
The filter is now filled with the strings but the filter doesn't work anymore, cause the Return Value (The number) doesn't match with the formated column.

Edit:
I just noticed, that the return value from the LoV doesn't matter at all, hence it is not possible to custom sort/filter a column?

Edit2:
I have also tried Plain-Text based on LoV for the column, with no luck on this...

Comment: Could you post the way you "formatted your number column" and LoV query?

Comment: Thank you; unfortunately, I don't have any ideas. I tried to simulate what you described, no luck. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: @Littlefoot thank you trying. I also tried computing but it still sorts the column based on whats shown... Is it maybe possible to intercept the column sort (asc/desc) via Javascript? This way I could re-select and add a order by clause. EDIT: Or is there a suitable format mask to format the number to "00h 00m 00s" ?

Comment: What if you make DURATION_STRING hidden, use it as the HTML Expression for DURATION_NUMBER, and add the LoV as well for filtering DURATION_NUMBER?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp that's what I have already done. The return value from the LoV is the same as the display value in the HTML output (proofed by object inspector) from the filter list. Thus, I think its a bug...

Comment: I've just checked and the help for Column Filter indicates that the LOV must only return one column (i.e. additional columns are ignored). So unfortunately for you this means the LOV can only filter on the underlying value, not on the displayed value. Demo: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=APEXTEST:SO58914087&c=JK64

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Thank you for your time and help. I must have overlooked this in the documentation. Sadly, it defeats the purpose of a LOV and should be re-considered to fully use the LOV for this section. You may answer this question based on your findings.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I came across your demo in the link again and wanted to ask, what exactly (and how) have you done this report in the demo? I would like to look further into this as I am now having the latest APEX version. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Too late for edit but is it possible to use (in my case) just a number (in seconds) and use a format mask to achieve the string "XXh XXm XXs" ?